# Method for avoiding random number repetition - python

Tags: python, arrays, random, noise

I am using the random number routines in python in the following code in order to create a noise signal.

```
res = 10
# Add noise to each X bin accross the signal

X = np.arange(-600,600,res)

for i in range(10000):
    noise = [random.uniform(-2,2) for i in xrange(len(X))]

# custom module to save output of X and noise to .fits file 
wp.save_fits('test10000', X, noise)

plt.plot(V, I)

plt.show()
```

In this example I am generate 10,000 'noise.fits' files, that I then wish to co-add together in order to show the expected 1/sqrt(N) dependence of the stacked noise root-mean-square (rms) as a function of the number of objects co-added.

My problem is that the rms follows this dependancy up until ~1000 objects, at which point it deviates upwards, suggesting that the random number generator.

Is there a routine or way to structure the code which will avoid or minimise this repetition? (Ideally with the number as a float in between a max and min value >1 and <-1)?

Here is the output of the co-adding code as well as the code pasted at the bottom for reference.

[image: The dependance of rms of the co-added signal to as a function of number objects stacked. The green line is the expected 1/sqrt(N) dependence.(Ignore the title and units, they are a left over from another project.)]

If I use the module random.random() the result is worse.
[image: Dependance of rms co-added noise on N for random.random(). Again green line is expected 1/sqrt(N)]

Here is my code which adds the noise signal files together, averaging over the number of objects.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

rms_arr =[]
#vel_w_arr = []
filelist = glob.glob('/Users/thbrown/Documents/HI_stacking/mockcat/testing/test10000/M*.fits')
filelist.sort()

for i in (filelist[:]):

    print(i)

    #open an existing FITS file
    hdulist = fits.open(str(i))

    # assuming the first extension is the table we assign data to record array
    tbdata = hdulist[1].data

    #index = np.arange(len(filelist))

    # Access the signal column
    noise = tbdata.field(1)

    # access the vel column
    X = tbdata.field(0)

    if i == filelist[0]:
        stack = np.zeros(len(noise))
        tot_rms = 0 

    #print len(stack)
    # sum signal in loop
    stack = (stack + noise)

    rms = np.std(stack)

    rms_arr = np.append(rms_arr, rms)

numgal = np.arange(1, np.size(filelist)+1)

avg_rms = rms_arr / numgal
```

Comment: I don't think you're getting anywhere near the period of the RNG. You probably have a bug.

Comment: Just to test if it's due to a weakness in the RNG, though, try using `random.SystemRandom` to generate the random numbers. That's intended to be cryptographically secure, so it's quite unlikely to have any unexpected statistical surprises.

Comment: I've run some tests and the problem still persists when using random.SystemRandom. I've also tried to find where my bug may be however I'm struggling.
The random routine seems sound so maybe it's in the adding routine but finding out where is proving tricky.
Any ideas?

Comment: For clarification this is the code I used with Random.SystemRandom
`rnd = random.SystemRandom()`
`for i in range(9000):`

    `X = np.arange(-600,600,res)`
    `X = X.tolist()noise = np.zeros(len(X))`
    
    `Y = [rnd.uniform(-2,2) for i in xrange(len(X))]`
    
    `noise = noise + Y`

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have some sort of other data going into the computation by mistake, would you? Maybe your glob is catching something you don't want.

Comment: How would I check for this? I'm not sure but my understanding is that I'm only accessing the 'noise' column from each file (which I can print and appears to be correct i.e rnd numbers between -2 and 2) and so it's simple enough not to be.